# Dont show 'pages in category' list in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

In media wiki on a category page it says 'Pages in category'
It then lists all of the pages in that category.

Is there a way I can hide this on one category page?

I will creating all the links to the pages on a table on this page instead, allowing me to further customise how it is presented to the user

Answer (score 2):

For posterity:

Without CategoryPageView hook, I added

```
.mw-category-generated
{
  visibility: hidden;
  display:none;
}
```

to:

```
MediaWiki:Common.css
```

MediaWiki version: 1.34.0

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need you users to be able to edit the category pages, the easiest way might be to use the [`CategoryPageView` hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/CategoryPageView), to completely replace the category pages with whatever you want to show there. For some examples of how to do that, see the list of [CategoryPageView extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:CategoryPageView_extensions).

If you want something more complex, you'll have to extend the classes  `CategoryPage` and `CategoryViewer`, do add whatever behaviour you want.

Then again, you could always just add

```
.mw-pages {display: none;}
```

to `MediaWiki:Common.css`, if you are satisfied with just hiding the pages for most users. This will not work if you have set [`$wgUseSiteCss`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseSiteCss) to `false` (it's true by default).